# Spring JPA - Different entities with same id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_a")
public class A extends BaseStringIdTableClass

@Entity
@Table(name = "view_b")
public class B extends BaseStringIdTableClass

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseStringIdTableClass implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String id;
```

And in the database i have two views

```
select * from view_a
|ID|ColumnA|....
|34222|some Value|....

select * from view_b
|ID|ColumnB|...
|34222|lla lla|...
```

I have therefore in the database different views. But the rows in this different views have the same ID.

Now i try to read the entities with the standard CRUD Repository.

```
A a = aRepository.findById("34222").get();
B b = bRepository.findById("34222").get();
```

In this case i can not find entity b. If i swop the two lines of code i can not find entity a.

I think the persistence context can at one time containt for a specific ID only one entity? Is this right. What can i do?

Repository definitions

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<A> {
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<B> {
```

Comment: i try.... always the second call (findById) throws an NoSuchElementException. if i call aRepository.findById first, it find an entity. if i call bRepository.findById first, if find an entity.

Comment: Will you update your question with Data source configuration ? That will help to understand your problem.

Comment: Having two entities with different classes and the same ID is not a problem. Something else is going on. Please provide the code of a test/simple application where you create the two instances. Persist them and query for them resulting in the exception.

Comment: There is nothing to persist because i am reading database views. The two lines are my complete code.

Comment: I added the repo definitons to my question.

Comment: What sql statements are getting executed?

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, turn on SQL tracing to see what SQL gets executed for each lookup. Also add any annotations that you use on the `aRepository` definition and/or on the repository interfaces, if any

Comment: There are no annotations on the repository. If i turn on sql tracing i cann see that there is executed a statement on the first call. And this call works fine. But on the second call there is not executed a statement.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with my inheritance. I updated my question.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Only  a stupid error, caused by a  lack of spring jpa knowledge....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleeping over one night always help....First sorry for my initial incomplete question.

The problem/error was the both entities extended the same abstract class. And in this abstract class the ID was definied.

Fix after this recogniton was easy. One of the entities does not extend my abstract class, but definies his own id. And now it works......